# Howto modify/affect/adapt conan dependencies

Tags: conan

I am not a conan expert, so maybe there is an obvious solution for this. But it can't be trivial since I am struggling with this for a while and can't find a solution.

We need parquet for our project, we include this via the conan arrow package like this, conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
arrow/2.0.0

[generators]
cmake

[options]
spdlog:=gcc
arrow:shared=False
arrow:parquet=True
arrow:fPIC=False
arrow:with_re2=False
arrow:with_protobuf=False
arrow:with_openssl=False
arrow:with_gflags=False
arrow:with_glog=False
arrow:with_grpc=False
arrow:with_utf8proc=False
arrow:with_zstd=False
arrow:with_bz2=False
```

(I remove all the other packages, but there are not so many of them)

The problem is on our CI we get the error:

```
...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt
Downloading conanfile.py
Downloading conan_export.tgz
thrift/0.13.0: Downloaded recipe revision 0
openssl/1.1.1j: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
openssl/1.1.1j: Trying with 'conan-center'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt
Downloading conanfile.py
Downloading conan_export.tgz
openssl/1.1.1j: Downloaded recipe revision 0
ERROR: openssl/1.1.1j: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at '/conan/.conan/data/openssl/1.1.1j/_/_/export/conanfile.py': Current Conan version (1.32.1) does not satisfy the defined one (>=1.33.0).
CMake Error at cmake/conan.cmake:368 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/conan.cmake:448 (conan_cmake_install)
  CMakeLists.txt:137 (conan_cmake_run)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/builds/0/corsika/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

indicating correctly that on CI we use containers with conan 1.32.1 and this seems to be in conflict with openssl/1.1.1j that wants >= 1.33.0.

I find that annoying because we explicitly don't want and don't need openssl and we switch it off for arrow (see above).

When I run `conan info .` I can see that:

```
conanfile.txt
    ID: 33d8c2433f5e03548c5229121dbd4f82e354000d
    BuildID: None
    Requires:
        arrow/2.0.0
arrow/2.0.0
    ID: cd50fd05198137f0420bf6da1e5029dade26bc93
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://arrow.apache.org/
    License: Apache-2.0
    Description: Apache Arrow is a cross-language development platform for in-memory data
    Topics: conan, arrow, memory
    Provides: arrow
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Missing
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2020-11-22 17:53:36 UTC
    Required by:
        conanfile.txt
    Requires:
        thrift/0.13.0
boost/1.75.0
    ID: d9d3e501899335bccbe5205508f9a4801424ce7d
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://www.boost.org
    License: BSL-1.0
    Description: Boost provides free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries
    Topics: conan, boost, libraries, cpp
    Provides: boost
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Download
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2021-04-13 19:51:36 UTC
    Required by:
        thrift/0.13.0
    Requires:
        zlib/1.2.11
        bzip2/1.0.8
        libiconv/1.16
bzip2/1.0.8
    ID: da606cf731e334010b0bf6e85a2a6f891b9f36b0
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: http://www.bzip.org
    License: bzip2-1.0.8
    Description: bzip2 is a free and open-source file compression program that uses the Burrows Wheeler algorithm.
    Topics: conan, bzip2, data-compressor, file-compression
    Provides: bzip2
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Cache
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2020-09-04 10:44:14 UTC
    Required by:
        boost/1.75.0
libevent/2.1.12
    ID: 6b0981c427aa0eb8bea05add2094df29ed639799
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://github.com/libevent/libevent
    License: BSD-3-Clause
    Description: libevent - an event notification library
    Topics: conan, libevent, event
    Provides: libevent
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Cache
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2021-03-18 17:32:39 UTC
    Required by:
        thrift/0.13.0
    Requires:
        openssl/1.1.1j
libiconv/1.16
    ID: 6af9cc7cb931c5ad942174fd7838eb655717c709
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/
    License: LGPL-2.1
    Description: Convert text to and from Unicode
    Topics: libiconv, iconv, text, encoding, locale, unicode, conversion
    Provides: libiconv
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Cache
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2020-10-04 02:46:44 UTC
    Required by:
        boost/1.75.0
openssl/1.1.1j
    ID: 6af9cc7cb931c5ad942174fd7838eb655717c709
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://github.com/openssl/openssl
    License: OpenSSL
    Description: A toolkit for the Transport Layer Security (TLS) and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) protocols
    Topics: conan, openssl, ssl, tls, encryption, security
    Provides: openssl
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Cache
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2021-03-26 21:05:40 UTC
    Required by:
        thrift/0.13.0
        libevent/2.1.12
thrift/0.13.0
    ID: 44b3a17b9712eb98c7cab65c26ec70335992ff20
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://github.com/apache/thrift
    License: Apache-2.0
    Description: Thrift is an associated code generation mechanism for RPC
    Topics: conan, thrift, serialization, rpc
    Provides: thrift
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Download
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2021-03-30 05:58:58 UTC
    Required by:
        arrow/2.0.0
    Requires:
        boost/1.75.0
        openssl/1.1.1j
        zlib/1.2.11
        libevent/2.1.12
zlib/1.2.11
    ID: 6af9cc7cb931c5ad942174fd7838eb655717c709
    BuildID: None
    Remote: conan-center=https://conan.bintray.com
    URL: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index
    Homepage: https://zlib.net
    License: Zlib
    Description: A Massively Spiffy Yet Delicately Unobtrusive Compression Library (Also Free, Not to Mention Unencumbered by Patents)
    Topics: conan, zlib, compression
    Provides: zlib
    Recipe: Cache
    Binary: Cache
    Binary remote: conan-center
    Creation date: 2020-11-15 04:53:34 UTC
    Required by:
        thrift/0.13.0
        boost/1.75.0
```

and it seem the reason openssl is pulled in is because of thrift and libevent.

So what are solution here given the fact that we cannot change our CI containers because then we basically drop support to platforms that we need to support?

- why openssl depends on conan version in the first place? Can't this we fixed or worked around?
- can we affect the dependency tree of arrow in a way to avoid any reference to openssl? E.g. provide dedicated versions of thrift/libevent that come without openssl (if this is even possible)?
- Are there any other options?

(As a footnote, the containers and systems we use are all not terribly outdated so I believe this problem can easily affect many users. I have not found any solution after search for a while. )

Comment: From the docs: "This means that public repositories, like ConanCenter assume the use of the latest version of the Conan client, and using an older version may result in failure of packages and recipes created with a newer version of the client." (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/introduction.html#stable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious recommendation: [Update](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html#update) Conan to the latest version (1.35.1).

```
pip install -U conan
```

Packages in Conan Center Index (all official) are not blocked by any old version, actually it's mandatory testing them with latest Conan version available. Conan Center Index assumes you are running latest Conan client version too:

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/41d4fbb8c218f9d938ccb8b9d888bff52002e62e/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md#L9

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/c060f7086f3745361795fb6379bd6f0bac000bab/docs/how_to_add_packages.md#L57

> why openssl depends on conan version in the first place? Can't this we fixed or worked around?

New Conan features are introduces for every new release. You can't simply change a recipe because you are consuming them. Even if you download the recipe and remove that check, it will fail, because your Conan client version doesn't support some method/feature in that recipe.

> can we affect the dependency tree of arrow in a way to avoid any reference to openssl? E.g. provide dedicated versions of thrift/libevent that come without openssl (if this is even possible)?

Yes, but is not recommended. You can declare other package versions consumed by arrow in your conanfile.txt, it will force Conan to use your versions.

> Are there any other options?

Yes, don't try workarounds, do the right thing, update your client version.

Comment: Thanks. This helps, unfortunately it means updating our docker containers since we keep the conan data inside the containers. But this is due to our setup.

Comment: You shouldn't keep conan data in your containers. Docker is not a virtual machine, you run, finish and remove your container. Your Conan Data should be stored in external volume. Take a look on official Conan Docker images: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools#use-the-images-locally

Comment: I would consider that for local use, but we only use the containers for gtilab-CI and have a worldwide very distributed Runner-hardware. The only point for adding conan data to the containers is increasing the throughput of the runners and saving resources on the CI. The artifact system of gitlab-CI typically leads to very poor performance (tried that) and docker is much better in handling our needs (slso the gitlab-CI caching is not very practical in our scenario).